# Connection Error while calling external api from AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, urllib3

I am trying to access an external api from aws glue script.

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://api.github.com/users/hadley/orgs")
```

I'm getting a connection error stating,

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.github.com/users/hadley/orgs', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb8ff471400>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',))
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not an [tag:apache-spark] question and I'm not sure I can provide an answer to your issue but what I would do is start from [here](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/big-data/how-to-access-and-analyze-on-premises-data-stores-using-aws-glue/). There seems work to do with the network configuration for AWS Glue in this case.

Comment: Same problem here. Have you been able to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this has been answered yet but go to "Edit job" and remove your required connection if you have one.  When you have a required connection it keeps you within your VPC not allowing for external connections.

Comment: Thank you, this quick input helped me fix my job.

Comment: Only thing that worked after messing up with whole networking :)